# docker macvlan static ip - yet a dhcp request

Tags: networking, dhcp, docker, static-ip

I'm trying to run 2 docker containers on my Raspberry Pi with each having it's own static ip address.

So far, I got it working using the macvlan network driver.
But there's this strange behaviour:

Whenever I start a container, my router (Fritz!Box 7590) is reporting a new network device and assigns a new ip to it. The container is reacheable on it's static ip and the automatically assigned ip is just unused and fills up the DHCP leases. Every (re-)start, a new unused ip.

How can I stop these unnecessary DHCP requests?

I'm just getting warm with docker, any help is appreciated!

-

My specific network and container configuration (my router's home network is on 192.168.2.x):

`docker network create -d macvlan --subnet=192.168.2.0/24 --gateway=192.168.2.1 -o parent=eth0 home_network`

`docker run -d --name "diyHue" -v '/mnt/hue-emulator/export/':'/opt/hue-emulator/export/':'rw' -e MAC='02:42:AC:F8:1B:B8' -e IP='192.168.2.241' -p 80:80/tcp -p 443:443/tcp -p 1900:1900/udp -p 2100:2100/udp -p 1982:1982/udp --ip 192.168.2.241 --mac-address 02:42:AC:F8:1B:B8 --network home_network --restart always diyhue/core:latest`

`docker run --init -d --name="home-assistant" -v /home/pi/homeassistant:/config -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro --network home_network --ip 192.168.2.242 --mac-address 02:42:AC:11:CE:10 --restart always homeassistant/raspberrypi3-homeassistant`

-

My other computers with static ips don't have this problem. They just startup and my router doesn't give them a new ip. The docker host has no problem either, only the containers.

I just restarted one container (only the container, not the host) a few times and noticed, the following:

- every new device has the hostname of my docker host ("pi-smarthome")
- every new device has a different mac address

It seems like docker is giving the container a random mac address on startup, connect them to the network and then change mac address and ip to the container's configuration afterwards.

Here's part of my router's DHCP device list:

hostname - ip address - mac address - extra dhcp info

```
"pi-smarthome" - 192.168.2.111 - 1A:26:4A:2E:CD:9C - dhcpcd-6.11.5:Linux-4.14.98-v7+:armv7l:BCM2835

"pi-smarthome" - 192.168.2.112 - 2A:16:03:84:CB:C1 - dhcpcd-6.11.5:Linux-4.14.98-v7+:armv7l:BCM2835

"pi-smarthome" - 192.168.2.113 - AE:25:25:0C:58:57 - dhcpcd-6.11.5:Linux-4.14.98-v7+:armv7l:BCM2835

"pi-smarthome" - 192.168.2.114 - 72:D6:5B:7C:3E:0D - dhcpcd-6.11.5:Linux-4.14.98-v7+:armv7l:BCM2835

"pi-smarthome" - 192.168.2.240 - B8:27:EB:B5:3F:67 - no extra dhcp info - (the real docker host)

"PC-192-168-2-241" - 192.168.2.241 - 02:42:AC:F8:1BB8 - no extra dhcp info - (the diyHue container)

"Home" - 192.168.2.242 - 02:42:AC:11:CE:10 - no extra dhcp info - (the home-assistant container)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had it at --net=home_network and then it worked for me (in stead of --network take --net.

first: 
docker network create -d macvlan --subnet=192.168.2.0/24 --gateway=192.168.2.254 --ip-range=192.168.2.100/28 -o parent=eth0 vlan

second:
docker run -d --name=iot -p 8080:8080 -p 4443:4443 --net=vlan -v /home/ubuntu/data/iot:/home/node/.mozilla-iot -e TZ='Europe/Amsterdam' mozillaiot/gateway:arm

I then set my router to never give out ip's above 192.168.2.100 (vlan does that now) do it will not conflict.